# How to change login database to PostgreSQL in sample C# ASP.NET WebForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, web-applications, asp.net-identity

I want to use login system provided with WebForms template, but it is configured to use MSSQL LocalDB, I tried to switch it and here are the steps I've made so far:

1. In Models\IdentityModels.cs replaced ": base("DefaultConnection")" to ": base("MyPgConnection")"
2. DEBUG -> Exceptions... -> Marked all except "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"
3. Started application, on first break - F11 - application started
4. Registration -> login/password -> submit: got an error 'relation "undefined" doesn't exsist'. However in the pg database appeared table _MigrationHistory!
5. Started application again, F11, excelption: 'relation "AspNetUsers" doesn't exsist': another table "AspNetRoles" appeared in Pg database!
6. Third launch - again 'relation "AspNetUsers" doesn't exsist'
7. Created a table similar to that in LocalDB

   ```
   CREATE TABLE "AspNetUsers"
   (
     "Id" character varying(128) NOT NULL,
     "Email" text NOT NULL,
     "EmailConfirmed" boolean NOT NULL,
     "PasswordHash" text,
     "SecurityStamp" text,
     "PhoneNumber" text,
     "PhoneNumberConfirmed" boolean NOT NULL,
     "TwoFactorEnabled" boolean NOT NULL,
     "LockoutEndDateUtc" timestamp,
     "LockoutEnabled" boolean NOT NULL,
     "AccessFailedCount" integer NOT NULL,
     "UserName" text NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT "AspNetUsers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
   )
   WITH (
     OIDS=FALSE
   );
   ALTER TABLE "AspNetUsers"
     OWNER TO postgres;
   ```
8. Fourth Launch: exception Column Extent1.Discriminator doesn't exist
9. Added "Discriminator" text NOT NULL, - exception: "Connection must be opened."

No idea where to open the connection, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Install `Npgsql.dll` and than try to make a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 provider that use Entity Framework for PostgreSQL. At the moment it was placed here https://github.com/vincechan/PostgreSQL.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

In my solution I added a project from the demo on this site and changed all

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

to

```
using PostgreSQL.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Then there was a tricky part:

In IdentityModels.cs after

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

and in MyDBContext.cs after

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext
```

I added:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // If you are letting EntityFrameowrk to create the database, 
        // it will by default create the __MigrationHisotry table in the dbo schema
        // Use HasDefaultSchema to specify alternative (i.e public) schema
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
    }
```

Then

```
public class MyDBContext: DbContext
```

changed to

```
public class MyDBContext: ApplicationDbContext
```

this makes both DBContexts to initialize simultaneously